# Are voltage and current in phase in a transmission line with a lossless medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, conductors

[image]

In electromagnetics, E and H are in phase in  a transmission line with a lossless medium.

So V and I are in phase.

But in power transmission line, usually I is lagging with V.

[image]

Since we mainly use inductive loads, although we are using various kinds of reactive power compensation devices, the current lags behind the voltage by the phase difference in the power transmission line.

Then, E and H must be out of phase.

Then, intrinsic constant of E and H?

How should I understand?

Comment: The terminations adds a boundary condition and part of the incident wave is transmitted and the other part is reflected with a resulting change of phase.

Comment: @Farcher  I appreciate for your guidance!

Comment: @Farcher   Then, the phase difference between E and H is exactly the same as the phase difference between V and I. Is it right?